# How can I determine the name of the OLE object to create in order to retrieve KBs through WMI?

Tags: c++, windows, go, winapi, com

I am trying to rewrite a C++ program that that retrieves all installed and superseded KBs on a Windows computer in Go.

The C++ program retrieves these KBs by querying for KBs from two different sources:

1. WMI, with the query `SELECT * FROM Win32_QuickFixEngineering`
2. Update history, with [`IUpdateSearcher::GetTotalHistoryCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iupdatesearcher-gettotalhistorycount) and [`IUpdateSearcher::QueryHistory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iupdatesearcher-queryhistory)

I am seeking help with translating #1 to Go.

I thought the best library I could use for this is [go-ole](https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole). As an example that uses this library, I looked at the source code for [github.com/ceshihao/windowsupdate](https://github.com/ceshihao/windowsupdate). I found that this library has the following in order to create an object for querying the update history ([source](https://github.com/ceshihao/windowsupdate/blob/94efa1c2d8dba7e7d81522507728ec8053d33c12/iupdatesession.go#L60)):

```golang
unknown, err := oleutil.CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
```

I believe this is roughly equivalent to this part of the C++ program I am rewriting (this is from the part that corresponds to item 2 in the list at the beginning of this post):

```cpp
result = updateSession.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UpdateSession, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
```

However, I do not know how to translate this line from a different part of the C++ program (this is from the part that corresponds to item 1 in the list at the beginning of this post):

```cpp
CComPtr<IWbemLocator> pLoc;

// <...>

// Obtain the initial locator to Windows Management
// on a particular host computer.
hres = pLoc.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
```

I assume the equivalent Go will be something like this:

```golang
unknown, err := oleutil.CreateObject("<mystery string>")
```

I tried looking at `CLSID_WbemLocator`'s definition using Visual Studio's "Go To Definition" feature, but it is just declared as

```cpp
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_WbemLocator;
```

which isn't very helpful.

My question is this: How can I determine what I should use as `"<mystery string>"` in order to create an object that is equivalent to what the C++ code creates with `CLSID_WbemLocator`?

Comment: If you're looking for a guid value, I've created this site specifically for interop-like scenarios https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=CLSID_WbemLocator However, in COM not every CLSID has a corresponding "ProgId" (like "Microsoft.Update.Session" => CLSID_UpdateSession) which seems to be needed by this oleutil thing (this package https://github.com/winlabs/gowin32 seens to fully allow CoCreateInstance call in go). Try `oleutil.CreateObject("WBEMComLocator")` (I've searched for the guid in registry and it appears in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WBEMComLocator)

Comment: Can you clarify why method 1 is needed considering that Microsoft documentation says: "The Win32_QuickFixEngineering class is derived from CIM_LogicalElement. Because updates are stored in two places, an enumeration of this class can result in duplicates."? Shouldn't the second method be enough to find everything?

Comment: Also, can you show the code that initializes `pLoc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to [IWbemLocator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nn-wbemcli-iwbemlocator) interface documentation.

`CLSID_WbemLocator` is declared as extern in `Wbemcli.h` header file for C programs and the CLSID (GUID) constant itself is stored in the library file `Wbemuuid.lib`. However, for C++ programs it is also defined in `Wbemcli.h` header file.

From the `Wbemcli.h` header file:

```
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_WbemLocator;

#ifdef __cplusplus

class DECLSPEC_UUID("4590f811-1d3a-11d0-891f-00aa004b2e24")
WbemLocator;
#endif
```

From the `Wbemuuid.lib` library (file `wbemcli_i.obj`):

[image: CLSID_WbemLocator]

From the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{4590F811-1D3A-11D0-891F-00AA004B2E24}`:

[image: Registry Editor showing CLSID_WbemLocator entry]

So the name is simply `WBEM Locator`.